# Thrift list as a mutable type

Tags: list, thrift, thrift-protocol

As taken from the thrift website's [documentation](https://thrift.apache.org/docs/types), a thrift list is "an ordered list of elements. Translates to an STL vector, Java ArrayList, native arrays in scripting languages, etc." Why are these lists expressed as mutable types? Doesn't this promote slower object types that don't take advantage of native arrays? I don't understand why the default - only - translation of a list in thrift is to a mutable array type.

Answer (score 0):

> As taken from the thrift website's documentation, a thrift list is "an ordered list of elements. Translates to an STL vector, Java ArrayList, native arrays in scripting languages, etc." Why are these lists expressed as mutable types?

One has to keep in mind that the type system of Thrift is designed with portability across languages as the first and most important goal in mind. That's also the reason why there are only signed integers.

Furthermore, the IDL types should be considered as an abstract **concept**, which describes more the intent of a particular type rather than referring to a concrete syntax construction in, let's say, Java, C++ or Python. Which leads us to the second part of your question:

> Doesn't this promote slower object types that don't take advantage of native arrays? I don't understand why the default - only - translation of a list in thrift is to a mutable array type.

The mapping from the IDL type down to a concrete implementation for a particular target language lies in the responsibility of the implementation of both Thrift compiler and Thrift library for the language in question. In other words, it is by no means set in concrete and can (at least theoretically) be changed at any time by changing those implementations.

But another goal is to not build too many roadblocks and potholes for the developer. Besides being fast and efficient, it should be easy to use the generated code and the library, it should be easy to do whatever your code wants to do with them. For example, C# classes are generated as partial classes to offer more flexibility. While immutable types may be more efficient in some cases, they may cause more work in other cases. At the end, this is kind of an balancing act.

If you can think of an improvement, the above is by no means intended to stop you from proposing quality patches. If your ideas can help making Thrift better, you are more than welcome and we will gladly review [your patches or pull requests](https://thrift.apache.org/docs/HowToContribute).